# How to process last row of csv file in node js using fast-csv before triggering 'end' event?

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, npm, callback

I am using fast-csv npm, but in the below code it is processing last row(3rd row) of csv data after triggering "end" event. How to resolve this issue?

**OUTPUT :**

here
processing request
here
processing request
here
end
processing request

**EXPECTED :**

here
processing request
here
processing request
here
processing request
end

```
var parser = csv.fromPath(filePath, {headers : true})
.on("data", function(data) {
  console.log('here');
  parser.pause();
//calling some api server
  api.createEmployee(data, function(err) {
    // TODO: handle error
    console.log('processing request');
    parser.resume();
  });
}).on("end", function(){
  console.log('end');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I added one flag variable and based on that called sleep method. Now it's working fine `require('deasync').sleep(100);`